# Unable to View Airpal UI

Tags: presto

i am unable to view Airpal Homepage.

Here is my reference.yml file.

---

## HTTP-specific options.

server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8010
      idleTimeout: 10 seconds

adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8082

shiro:
  iniConfigs: ["classpath:shiro_allow_all.ini"]

dataSourceFactory:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: root
  password: root
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airpal

flywayFactory:
  locations: ["classpath:db.migration.common", "classpath:db.migration.mysql"]

## The URL to the Presto coordinator.

prestoCoordinator: http://presto-coordinator-url.com

---

**Here is my error when i am running this command.**

java -server \
     -Duser.timezone=UTC \
     -cp build/libs/airpal-*-all.jar com.airbnb.airpal.AirpalApplication server reference.yml

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener.lifeCycleStarting(SetUIDListener.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setStarting(AbstractLifeCycle.java:187)
WARN  [2016-02-22 20:23:50,071] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2125ad3: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
! java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

After struggling i just stopped prestoserver and ran the airpal command and now i can see Airpal homepage